# How to call javascript methods on Ajax CalendarExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I am using Ajax toolkit's Calendar Extender for taking date, now I want to call a javascript method on calendar's date selection change event, how do I do this?
I am using following code for this

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" PopupButtonID="divCalendar"   TargetControlID="TxtHiddenFieldCalenderValue" >
```

and calling javascript method:-

```
function dateChanged(){
    alert("date");
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have javascript function like,

```
function checkDate(sender,args)
{
    alert("hello");
}
```

and your ASP.net Code like these

```
<asp:CalendarExtender OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate" PopupButtonID="XX" runat="server" TargetControlID="targetID" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Enabled="True"></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Hope this would be helpful.

```
sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format)  will give you selected date by Ajax Calender Extender.
```